# "recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow" on overloaded << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a section of code that seems to have a recursive warning when I compile, any ideas why?

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const node& rhs)
    {
        out << rhs.get_data();
        return out;
    }
```

It is calling this function:

```
node::value_type node::get_data() const
    {
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore it's a string, sorry.

Comment: @AndreasHenning Visual Studio

Comment: @TobyBloem then why isn't it called `std::string`?

Comment: have you tried parentheses around rhs.get_data()? (just a rough guess...) - also, if you can, have a look what errors you get from gcc

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's a requirement of the assignment I'm doing to use value_types

Comment: @TobyBloem how is it defined?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore typedef std::string value_type;

Comment: This should work - http://ideone.com/DiMmO

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you really shouldn't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @AndreasHenning I shouldn't use it when providing a sample to prove a point? Why?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore that doesn't seem different to what I have already, although node is a class in my assignment

Comment: @LuchianGrigore because the sample you provide may just be used by someone.

Comment: @TobyBloem that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @TobyBloem Have you tried compiling Luchian's code? If it compiles correctly in your platform (and it should), then the problem is in a part of the code you are not showing, so we cannot help you.

Comment: @Gorpik yeah, it compiles fine. The node class is part of a much larger program. I think the problem may lie when it tries to print a node that data is NULL or empty, but I can't find where that's happening

Comment: @TobyBloem That shouldn't matter, since the compiler doesn't know the contents of `data`. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess, since you haven't posted a self-contained example. In particular, the definition of `node` would be very useful.

I think that, for some reason, the compiler is choosing to convert `rhs.get_data()` into a `node`, probably using an implicit conversion constructor, rather than selecting an overload of `operator<<` that takes `node::value_type`. You should:

- Make sure that `operator << (ostream&, node::value_type)` has been declared before your definition of `operator<<`
- If `node` has a constructor that takes `value_type`, then it's probably best to make it `explicit` to avoid unexpected implicit conversions.